# Strange Behavior with mongoid date range query. - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am running in very strange date range query problem. When I use DateTime.now.utc option to query database, the query date for DateTime.now is different that my current DateTime.now(i.e. one that's returned on console.)

My mogoid.yml uses-

```
use_utc: true
```

I have my named scope like this -

```
scope :running_auctions, {
       :where => { :end_time.gt => DateTime.now.utc },
       :order_by => [:end_time, "ASC"]
 }
```

And on console I can do this -

Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.7)

```
irb(main):001:0> Auction.running_auctions
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
selector: {:end_time=>{"$gt"=>Fri Jul 22 00:42:38 UTC 2011}},
options:  {:sort=>[:end_time, "ASC"]},
class:    Auction,
embedded: false>
```

Notice that my date here is Fri Jul 22 00:42:38 UTC 2011

```
irb(main):002:0> DateTime.now
=> Fri, 22 Jul 2011 11:42:56 +0530

irb(main):003:0> DateTime.now.utc
=> Fri, 22 Jul 2011 06:12:59 +0000
```

Notice here that my datetime is Fri, 22 Jul 2011 06:12:59 +0000

What is making query date older than actual current date ? Does mogoid or mongodb doing caching there ?
Please let me know if I am missing something.

UPDATE

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.7)
irb(main):001:0> Auction.running_auctions(DateTime.now.utc)
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
 selector: {:end_time=>{"$gt"=>Fri Jul 22 01:21:53 UTC 2011}},
 options:  {:sort=>[:end_time, "ASC"]},
 class:    Auction,
 embedded: false>

irb(main):002:0> DateTime.now.utc
=> Fri, 22 Jul 2011 06:52:03 +0000
```

Comment: can you update the question with the scope code and the call to scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a lambda there. As of now, the `DateTime.now.utc` is computed at application startup and cached with application code.

You need to write your scope as:

```
scope :running_auctions, lambda {
  {
    :where => { :end_time.gt => DateTime.now.utc },
    :order_by => [:end_time, "ASC"]
  }
}
```

Comment: I passed date to scope like running_auctions(DateTime.now.utc) and cached it like lambda{|date| ..otherstuff..} which worked for me.. running your same code didn't gave current date, but old date only..

Comment: You don't need to pass the date. Writing the scope word to word should work.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but can you tell what's different between UTC 2011 and +0000 format date? I have edited my code to show what i mean by this. See that on console my DateTime.now.utc is different i.e. +0000 format and in query it's UTC 2011 format.

Comment: UTC and +0000 mean same, for example "Asia/Kolkata" and +0530 mean same. They are just different formats, probably because one is using your application default format and other is set by mongoid. But your update still has different Datetimes!!

Comment: yes, so i am still stuck with date issue. As scope uses UTC 2011 fomate which is different than current date of format +0000.

Comment: @rtdp let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1722/discussion-between-rubish-gupta-and-rtdp)

Comment: Rubish, thanks for help. Figured out that my local server and browser was with IST and while staging server was UTC with broswer IST and that was creating so much confusion. Finally set dev machine to UTC and solved it. Thanks again.